# How to make a table data persistent after refreshing a JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a dynamic table that gets generated and populated from database. I wanted to make the whole table data or table persistent, so that if the page is refreshed in a simple submit or click button it doesn't go off. I tried doing this for learning purpose if its possible, but no luck

```
<form id="form3" value="inherit" method=post>
     <input type="hidden" name="nm" value="inherited">
    <Table id="dummy" name="table_dummy" border="1">
  <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Libraries</th>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Courses</th>
     </tr>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${result.getCategory().size() - 1}">
        <TR>
            <TD id="getC" name="td1">
                    ${result.getCategory().get(i)}
            </TD>

            <TD id='td1' name='td_n'>
                    ${result.getHeader().get(i)}
            </TD>
            <TD>
                    ${result.getLibs().get(i)}
            </TD>
            <TD>
                    ${result.getStudents().get(i)}
            </TD>
            <TD>
                    ${result.getCourses().get(i)}
            </TD>

        </TR>
    </c:forEach>
</TABLE>
```

//Below is the logic I am trying to use to make it persistent.

```
<% String trial = request.getParameter("td_n"); %> 

<script>
   document.getElementById("td1").value = '<% out.print(trial); %>
</script>
```

But, if I try for Table it doesn't work but if I try for any `<Form>` element like `<Select>`,`<input>` it does work.

Any comments/hints/links or any useful information on this would be really great!

**[EDIT]** Code Update as per discussion:

1. Have dynamic table that is getting populated from database, once the submit button is hit, that calls a servlet make connection to POSTGRESQL and send response.

2.Further, another table would get generated using a radio button click functionality which again calls the same servlet and generate new table shown above.

`<Servlet>`Side code:

```
 if("inherited".equals(nm)){

               InheritedResponse ir = null;
                InheritedDAOImpl iad = new InheritedDAOImpl();
                String sql ="select * from testTable";
                ir = iad.getInheritData(sql);
                System.out.println(sss);
                req.setAttribute("result",ir);
                Util.forward(req,resp,this, "/practice/trial.jsp");
```

Comment: please add more codes about how you show the database records its hard  to give you solution.post the exact code.

Comment: @sunleo: Updated the question with my code

Comment: I don't know the what u mean by "Util".But if you use the Dispatcher it will bring data once again from DB.There is no doubt.

Comment: Thanks @sunleo, `Util` is a class where I have created a method called `forward` that uses `Dispatcher`. What do you suggest I should change to make it work accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

1. `TD` is not element of the form. You can submit only form elements like `input`.
2. Then it's better to use `JSTL` instead of scriptlets on the page.
3. `TD` does not have attribute `value`. For `TD` it should be like:

   `document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML='some value'`;

Comment: Thank you Alex, Yes I know using scriptlets is not a very good idea, but I wanted to try and see if I can use that and be able to make my dynamic table persistent. can you please suggest how can I achieve that?

Comment: @akiiddweeber Store your values in `<input type="hidden">`, `<input type="text">` or other elements. Try to use `MVC` framework otherwise it's not practicable.

Comment: Thank you once again Alex, can you please guide some more how can I use `<input type="hidden">` in terms of `<Table>` or any link to such examples, as I am not very sure how to plugin that thing into this?

Comment: @akiiddweeber It's better to use existing libraries to generate a table like `DisplayTag` http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-nocolumns.jsp

Comment: Great, thank you Alex! I will go through the link for having more understanding. Can I further be able to preserve the data meaning maintaining the `persistent` state via using `DisplayTag`

Comment: Have a look at `Struts` or `Spring MVC` together with `DisplayTag` or any other similar libraries.

Comment: And this example about submitting a form: http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-checkboxes.jsp and this simple usage: http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_basic.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `input` element this way (just an example):

```
<pre>
<input type="text" value="${result.getCourses().get(i)}">
</pre>
```

Comment: Are you sure about those `<pre>`?